# SQLite Password Recovery

Tags: sqlite

I have forgotten my SQLite db password. Is there any way I can recover the password?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Basic sqlite doesn't support encrypting the database, so you need to tell us what you are using to encrypt it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible for a list of options.

Answer (score 2):

The [SQLite Encryption Extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) encrypts all of the data stored in a database, every byte including all headers.  The encryption key is not stored anywhere.  The only way to get back the key is a brute force attack.  afaik there are no existing tools to do this and even if there were it would take a really long time (depends on the key size).

Answer (score -3):

**VSPL SQLite Password Recovery to Recover SQLite Password**

The interaction for resting SQLite Server Password is genuinely simple executable however is far unexpected cycle in comparison to recuperation of SQLite Server Password. VSPL SQLite Password Recovery Software is the best device that gives simple cycle to reset, recuperate and open SQLite Password

https://www.vartikasoftware.com/product/sqlite-password-recovery.html