# how can i password protect my sqlite db in C. is it possible to partition the sqlite db?

Tags: sqlite

I am working on embedded system and the device has linux kernel with sqlite database. Wanted to know if the sqlite database can be partitioned with secure and normal partitions.

How can the encryption be achieved for sqlite database file in linux.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am too late to answer this question, but I was facing this issue from couple of days and couldn't find any solid solution online. I have found solution hence I am sharing it.

//Steps to make sqlite database authenticated

1. download sqlite3 amalgamation zip file
2. unzip the file. The file should contain shell.c, sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, sqlite3ext.h
3. click on [find the link here](http://www.sqlite.org/src/dir?ci=bee2859b953c935c&name=ext/userauth)

3a. Open userauth.c and copy the entire code and paste it at the end of your sqlite3.c file.

3b. Open sqlite3userauth.h and copy the entire code and pase it at the end of your sqlite3.h file.

4. create a output file for executing the command in shell
   command: `gcc -o sqlite3Exe shell.c sqlite3.c -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION -ldl -lpthread`

4a. Youll get error no such file "sqlite3userauth.h" in your shell.c file:
solution: go to that file and comment th line.(this is because youve already included the necessary code when you copied sqlite3auth.h into sqlite3.h)

4b. Test your output file by running `./sqlite3Exe` (this is the name youve given to the output file generated in previous step). you'll get sqlite console.

4c. Create a database and on the authentication flag:

command1: `.open dbname.db`

command2: `.auth on`

command3: `.exit`//command 3 is optional

5. Building the library
   5a: creating object file
   //Compiling sqlite3.c to create object after appending our new code

command: `gcc -o sqlite3.o -c sqlite3.c -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION`

With this command, we generate object file which we can use to compile our c file.

6. Create c file to authenticate your database:

   ```
   //authUser.c
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "sqlite3.h"
    int main(int argc,char * argv[]){
        int a = 10;
        int rtn, rtn2;
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *sql, *zErMsg;
        rtn = sqlite3_open("dbname.db", &db);
        rtn = sqlite3_user_add(db,"username","password",2, 1);//last but   one param is for number of bytes for password, last param is for weather the user is admin or not
        if(rtn){
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n",     sqlite3_errmsg(db));
              return(0);
            }else{
              fprintf(stderr, "Protected database successfully\n");
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
            return 0;
    }
   ```
7. Compiling the program
   //Compiling the program
   command1: `gcc authUser.c sqlite3.o -lpthread -ldl`
   command2: `./a.out` //Output:protected database successfully
8. create c file to create table if the user is authenticated

   ```
   //createTable.c
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "sqlite3.h"
    static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
       int i;
       for(i=0; i less then argc; i++){
          printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
       }
       printf("\n");
       return 0;
    }
    int main(int argc,char * argv[]){
        int a = 10;
        int rtn, rtn2;
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *sql, *zErMsg;
        rtn = sqlite3_open("dbname.db", &db);
        rtn = sqlite3_user_authenticate(db, "user","password",2);
        if(rtn){
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
              return(0);
            }else{
              fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
            }
        sql = "create table newtable(id int not null primary key, name varchar(100) not null)";
        //sql = "insert into newtable values(5, 'ishwar')";
        rtn = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErMsg);
        if(rtn != SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_free(zErMsg);
        }else{
            fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully \n");
            //fprintf(stdout, "inserted successfully \n");
        }
            sqlite3_close(db);
            return 0;
    }
   ```

   `
9. compiling the program
   //Compiling the program

command1: `gcc createTable.c sqlite3.o -lpthread -ldl`

command2: `./a.out` //Output:Table created successfully

10. Create c file to add values in table

from the previous code, you can see two sql variable and two fprintf inside else, now uncomment the commented line and comment the other one. and runt the same command as above
output: Inserted successfully

And youre done, try experimenting with the code, change the values of sqlite3_user_authenticate function you wont be able to do these operations,at max you may be able to open database(when you comment the sqlite3_user_authenticate functon.nothing else)

11. Testing it with shell

Run the command: `./sqlite3Exe` (the output file we created in step 4)

command1: `.open dbname.db`

command2: `.tables` //you should get error, user_auth

Thank you(please feel free to mail me in case of any problem: ishwar.rimal@gmail.com)

Comment: I followed all the steps and authentication works in the code but the database is still accessible from sqlite3Exe without authentication, i.e in step 11 i get the tables. Any idea why ?

Comment: @ishwar-rimal I get `Can't open database: no such function: sqlite_crypt` on `rtn = sqlite3_user_add(db,"username","password",2, 1);` what does it mean?

Comment: @sotiris Do you also get `Can't open database: no such function: sqlite_crypt`? how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

David Segleau here, Director of Product Management for Berkeley DB.

The recent 5.1 release of Oracle Berkeley DB (5.1.7) integrates the Berkeley DB encryption feature with the SQLite-based SQL API. You can read about it [here](http://bit.ly/hjQtqf).

Answer (score 0):

for encryption to be achieved with SQLite, you need to license some extensions from the SQLite author.

http://www.sqlite.org/support.html