# iPhone App data security

Tags: iphone, security, sqlite

I've been thinking about the design/art/music side of my app. However I realise that the data within the app can be compromised. Such as the high scores or a SQLite file containing the answers and questions to a trivia game.

- How do I go about stopping people like this?
- What steps should I take?
- Should I even worry about it?

The only people who would try to hack my app would be those that run jailbroken devices right? Not those with the official firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encrypt your SQLite Data.

[Password Protect a SQLite DB. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I go about stopping people like this?

Don't store sensitive data on the client. If protecting those answers is that important to you then have users submit their answer to a server and return if they answered it correctly.

> What steps should I take?

Don't trust data from clients. Calculate scores server side if possible instead of trusting a user to tell you what their score is. If no server is involved and you support some form of multiplayer you could have each client validate each other's scores and end the game if they disagree.

> Should I even worry about it?

Probably not but consider what damage a malicious client could cause and how that compares to the work required to mitigate that damage.

> The only people who would try to hack my app would be those that run jailbroken devices right?

No, I can download your app in iTunes and pull apart the .ipa file without running it on any device, jailbroken or not.