# Differences between SQLite and MySQL - login and security

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

At first I searched in Stack Overflow about the difference between MySQL and SQLite. So there is some answers but still I want to know something. When accessing MySQL I need to give host, username, password and database parameters. But when accessing SQLite I just give database name. Can anyone explain me this why, and for security reasons also, should not be there password for SQLite database, can not be it just downloaded for example from server, so I am totally stuck. So need your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that MySQL is a database server, while SQLite is a database engine that works against single database files.

You are correct that the SQLite database file could just be downloaded if it's placed right in the web application where anyone can reach it.

Most server providers offer a folder where you can place files like this, so that the web application itself can reach it, but it's not directly downloadable.

You can also optionally add protection to the SQLite database file. See this question:
[Password Protect a SQLite DB. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is mainly used for mobile and tablet apps.So they are just used for a single system.

But in MySql its a complete database and can be used from multiple system. So for increasing security ,we have to give all these. So that no one can misuse the data...

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is just a file. If you have read access to the file that is the implicit security model (as well as the possibility to use **database encryption**).

MySQL is a network service. It can listen on an internet facing socket, meaning anyone in the world can access it if they have the right authentication credentials.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is file based, MySQL is a service which runs on the server. With SQLite you don't need to enter the database name, but actually the database file.

If you put the database file at an inaccessible location, you should be totally fine and the user will not be able to download the file.