# Open a password protected sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

I have created a password protected sqlite database. I want to be able to view the database so that I can check that things are being inserted correctly during the development of my project. I have downloaded the sqlite database browser but this doesn't seem to let you open an encrypted database.

Is there a way that I can open the database file.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What SQLite database browser are you using?

Comment: Its the Sqlite browser on sourceforge. Its from http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 15):

The free [SQLite2009 Pro](http://osenxpsuite.net/?xp=3) browser will let you open SQLite databases which were encrypted with System.Data.SQLite.

When you open the file you get a warning saying that the file is encrypted or not a database, and are then prompted to select an encryption type, select "RSA".

Edit:

You may find [SQLite2009 Pro](http://osenxpsuite.net/?xp=3) is not as reliable as [sqliteadmin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) (which does not open databases encrypted with System.Data.SQLite). I just found it crashed upon trying to open a database which had a problem with one of the views.

I ended up [removing the encryption](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/130/452.aspx), and opening it with [sqliteadmin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/), which did not crash but instead put a little red cross over the view which had a problem. What a nice touch :-)

Comment: This answer really helped me, it is a shame that the OP didnt accept it

Comment: hi, i have downloaded this software but it allows only to open ".db3" file. as my sqlite database is having ".sqlite" extension. any solution?

Comment: That is just an unnecessary restriction in the dialog box, you can use SQLite2009 Pro to open files regardless of their extension. Right-click on your db file in its folder and select "open with..." then select the exe for SQLite2009 Pro, or drag the file onto the exe (assuming you're on Windows), or pass the file path to the exe via the cmd line.

Comment: in the open file dialog,go to the directory that containt the db file,type *.* in filename text field,then you can see all file in this directory, and then you can select the [NAME].sqlite file

Comment: @jack jin Or just make a copy of the .sqlite file and rename the copy to .db3

Comment: @fedeteka that's a good idea.  in my comment, i means type [asterisk].[asterisk] in the filename text filed

Comment: I am working on a winforms application, should I use ms access as database or sqlite db for security? I can password protect ms access also. Which is better ??

Answer (score 9):

You can open and create a password protected [sqlite](https://sqlite.org) database with [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt):

[image: see open image]

[image: see create image]

Comment: such a nice and decent tool. the best thing is that support different versions of sqlite including microsoft System.Data.sqlite

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the tool. It was awesome working with it.

Comment: How to open such password protected file then for reading to connect to a webssite using html php ? thanks

Comment: This is working in August 2022 using SQLite Studio, I encrypted my SqLite DB in .NET Core 6 using the following MS Docs --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli