# Security of SQLite databases in Android

Tags: java, c#, android, sqlite, encryption

I'm planning to use SQLite in my android app. But problem is, SQLite doesn't support Encryption officially without a license of SQLite Encryption Extention. So I just kept searching without any hope, and found something interesting. [This link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Protecting_a_SQLite_database_1219777_11.jsp) explains how to use SQLite encryption with AES 256 on the BlackBerry devices. And I could also get the information of how to use SQLite encryption in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190672/can-i-password-encrypt-sqlite-database).

**1. Google android OS or other phone manufacturers support the function like BlackBerry as well?**

**2. Can I use SetPassword() method of SQLiteConnection class in C# without any plugin?**

(I'm also developing an app in Unity5, so if the answer of No.2 is yes, it'll be very helpful. So I tried but only to fail)

Comment: On Android, we generally use [SQLCipher for Android](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android), though I have no idea if somebody has created C# bindings for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've heard of it. Is it free? Anybody knows if I can use it in C# too?

Comment: It is open source, BSD-licensed.

Comment: The only problem is it's fairly old, the bindings haven't been updated in years.