# sqlite unable to open database file is encrypted or is not a database?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I am working on a windows application .net 2.0 with sqlite database, my connection string stays in app.config like

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SQLiteDB" 
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|database.s3db;version=3;password=mypassword;" 
     providerName="System.Data.Sqlite"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In the connection string i have defined password as "mypassword" if i remove this password everything is working well but when i use password clause, it gives me error in connection.open() syntax that

```
File opened that is not a database file
file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I searched on net and found some version issue but i am using version 3 only as i stated in connection string i also tried removing the "version=3" but problem remains the same.

I am doing this first time, what is the solution of it?

Comment: I got this error message because I tried to open the db file with `sqlite` but what i should have used is `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you specify a password in the connection string, and the database already exists, SQLite assumes the database is encrypted and will try to decrypt it with said password. If you haven't set a password on the database yet, this will result in the "file is encrypted" error, because the supplied password can't be used to decrypt an unencrypted database.

You can either delete the database, and SQLite will create a new encrypted database using the password in the connection string. Or, you can encrypt your existing database using the `ChangePassword()` method:

```
// Opens an unencrypted database    
SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=c:\\test.db3");    
cnn.Open();    

// Encrypts the database. The connection remains valid and usable afterwards.    
cnn.ChangePassword("mypassword");
```

Reference: [Encrypting, decrypting and attaching to encrypted databases](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/130.aspx)

Comment: +1, thanks a lot it's working but only first time it worked flawlessly but when i run the application second time it it again showing the same exception on con.open that "File opened that is not a database file
file is encrypted or is not a database"

Comment: @harhar please outline the steps you took to encrypt your database. If you used the `ChangePassword()` method, you'll want to remove it from subsequent calls.

Comment: after con.Open(); i write con.ChangePassword("password"); and after working with it i do con.ChangePassword(""); and finally con.Close(); is it wrong ?

Comment: @harhar if you want to specify the password in the connection string, then call `ChangePassword("mypassword")` one time to set the encryption on the database (and don't call it again unless you really want to change the password). Remove the call to `ChangePassword("")` entirely, because that's removing the encryption from your database - which is why the next time you try to open it with the connection string password you get the "file is encrypted" error again.

Comment: I didn't get why you would get the error that the "file is encrypted" again when you try `conn.ChangePassword("")`, if you are removing encryption by blanking the password. But if you call the DB with a password in the string, I found that is what happens - the DB is probably trying to decrypt with that password, and encryption is removed when the password is removed. `conn.SetPassword("something"); conn.Open()`, and call it with that password in the connection string. To change it, you could blank it w/change, but then you have to remove the Password parameter from the connection string.

Comment: @2Toad "SQLite", that I know of, doesn't re-create your DB if you delete it and try to reconnect to a now deleted DB - at least from a C# .NET call.  That's like saying I can create a database in SQL Server just by instantiating `SqlConnection`.  You have to have something to connect to, or it will just give you an error.

Comment: For me there is nothing like conn.SetPassword() . I also dont hve a conn.ChangePassword(). and I get this error - SQL logic error
Cannot use "Password" connection string property: library was not built with encryption support, please see "https://www.sqlite.org/see" for more information

Answer (score 7):

Check the version of SQLite. Some databases can be opened only by sqlite3.

Answer (score 6):

2Toad's answer is mostly correct, but I wanted to add my own because there are some clarifications to be made.  As 2Toad said, this is correct:

> When you specify a password in the connection string, and the database already exists, SQLite assumes the database is encrypted and will try to decrypt it with said password. If you haven't set a password on the database yet, this will result in the "file is encrypted" error, because the supplied password can't be used to decrypt an unencrypted database.

But this error can also happen if you try to use `conn.SetPassword("something")` after you already had another one in the connection string.  Or if you do `conn.ChangePassword("somethingelse")`, but still have `Password=something` in the connection string.

There are several scenarios to consider:

1. The database has had a password applied, and it is in the connection string.
2. You have a password in the connection string, but the database does not have one applied, or the password in the string does not match the DB.
3. The database has never had a password, and you want to change it.
4. The database has had a password, and you want to change it.

**Resolutions:**

1. So the code 2Toad provided to perform `conn.ChangePassword("somethingelse")` is only half-correct and doesn't take into account where you are, what else you've done, and what you want to do in the future.  If you have an existing password and you want to change it, this is correct, but you also have to be sure the connection string is updated afterwards, or subsequent connections will fail with the `file is encrypted` error.
2. This scenario happens if you blank the password using `conn.SetPassword("")` and then try `conn.ChangePassword("somethingelse")` without first connecting to the database without the `Password=something` in the connection string. That `Password=something` would have to be removed from the connection string, because the password has been removed programmatically from the DB and the DB will try connecting with that.  If it's not removed from the connection string at the same time as it's removed from the DB programmatically, you'll get the same `file is encrypted` error.
3. Because I started out by doing a `conn.SetPassword("something")` in the very beginning when I didn't have a password applied (and I believe this is the way to do that), I cannot verify the following without creating another SQLite DB, but I do not believe you can call `conn.ChangePassword("something")` if you never had a password in the first place.  You should do `conn.SetPassword("something")` for the initial set, and then put `Password=something` in your connection string.
4. The way I did a change of a password was where I did `conn.ChangePassword("somethingelse")` only after doing `conn.SetPassword("")` and clearing the `Password=something` from the connection string:

   ```
   // Changes an encrypted database to unencrypted and removes password
   string connString = "Data Source=c:\\test.db3;Password=something";    
   SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
   conn.SetPassword("");
   //conn.Open();    // doesn't work because connString hasn't been updated

   // Update connString
   connString = "Data Source=c:\\test.db3;";    
   conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
   conn.Open();  // we've opened the DB without a password

   // Re-encrypts the database. The connection remains valid and usable afterwards until closed - then the connection string needs updating.    
   conn.ChangePassword("somethingelse");
   conn.Close();

   // Update connString
   connString = "Data Source=c:\\test.db3;Password=somethingelse";   
   conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString); // must re-instantiate!
   conn.Open();  // we've opened the DB with our new password
   ```

This worked out fine.  I suppose you can also not clear it from the connection string and simply do `conn.ChangePassword("somethingelse")`, and then add `Password=somethingelse` to your string, afterwards:

```
    // Opens an encrypted database   
    string connString = "Data Source=c:\\test.db3;Password=something";    
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();    

    // Encrypts the database. The connection remains valid and usable afterwards until closed - then the connection string needs updating.    
    conn.ChangePassword("somethingelse");
    conn.Close();

    // Update connString
    connString = "Data Source=c:\\test.db3;Password=somethingelse";   
    conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();     // we've opened the DB with our new password
```

Personally, I store the password as encrypted in an app (web) .config file, and call it into a variable in my application onload and dynamically build my connection string from it.

That I know of, if you delete a SQLite DB and try to call it, you will simply get an error - not a re-created SQLite DB with a new password from your connection string - at least when using and calling it from a C# .NET app.

**UPDATE** If you need a function that will be used for updating the password after you already have one, you don't want to have `.SetPassword()`, but `.ChangePassword()`.  I found it is also better to always blank it out, then change it, like in my first example in #4.