# Can't open Sqlite db create in Python with sqlite command bash

Tags: python, sqlite

So if I create a db in Python using the sqlite3 package:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
```

I can't open the db using the sqlite command line in bash:

```
sqlite test.db
Unable to open database "test": file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I can however connect to a db created with the sqlite command line using sqlite3 in Python.

How can I open the Python created dbs in the sqlite command line?

Comment: Have you read these posts: about version mismatch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513849/error-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database or about password problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030601/sqlite-unable-to-open-database-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database-c?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Install `sqlite3` and use `sqlite3 test.db` in bash.