# VB NET AND SQLITE : file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, encryption

I am trying to create an apps with VB.NET and SQLite, i have create the database and table with SQLiteManager and **I HAVE SET ENCRYPTION TO THE DATABASE and THE PASSWORD IS SAME AS WHAT IN THE CONNECTION STRING**.

However when i am trying to insert sample record to table, it gave an error `file is encrypted or is not a database`

This is the sample of the code that produce the error.

```
Using ConLite = OpenConLite()
        Using LiteCmd As New SQLiteCommand
            Dim TglWaktuSekarang As String = CurrentDateTime()
            LiteCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO finger_stamp(emp_id,emp_name,date_time) VALUES('1','DIANA','" & TglWaktuSekarang & "')"
            LiteCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            LiteCmd.Connection = ConLite
            LiteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
End Using
```

and this is my connection code

```
 Public Function OpenConLite() As SQLiteConnection
    Dim SQLiteCon As SQLiteConnection
    Try
        Dim ConLiteString As String = "Data Source=C:\SQLiteDB\attendance.sqlite;Version=3;Password=hahaha;"
        SQLiteCon = New SQLiteConnection(ConLiteString) ' Connection DataSource
        SQLiteCon.Open()
        OpenConLite = SQLiteCon
    Catch ex As Exception
        OpenConLite = Nothing
        MsgBox("Failed to connect to Database", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Warning")
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite unable to open database file is encrypted or is not a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030601/sqlite-unable-to-open-database-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database)

Comment: nah, that's not me, from that post it say that `When you specify a password in the connection string, and the database already exists, SQLite assumes the database is encrypted and will try to decrypt it with said password. If you haven't set a password on the database yet, this will result in the "file is encrypted" error, because the supplied password can't be used to decrypt an unencrypted database.` but for my case, the database created with encryption.

Comment: Did you try to remove the password from the connection string? are you sure the password is the correct one?

Comment: tried to remove the password from the connection string, but still gave the same error, also i am sure that the password is correct