# What Database type should I choose for my VB .Net desktop app?

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

well I need some suggestion from someone who already know what type of database for my application is the best.
I have tried to play with My.Settings type stored data and also MS-Access.
But I was wondering if I will made some Password manager app, and if my database will be installed in C drive of user, if someone will find the database, he could easy open it and see all passwords and datas,
Thank you for suggestion as I really need some help on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the file database SQLite, with SQLite Studio (for Free) and it's great staff, if you don't need robust data storage solution.

Here are some recommendations, how to set password:
[Password Protect a SQLite DB. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible)

Pluses:

- common SQL,
- single file,
- simple according to my mind.

and many more.

Comment: thx m8 but I need to know what type of database should I start to learn, what is the best solution for my vb net app, and also I would liek to hide databse in app somewhere, to prevent other user on computer like at school exemple to open ms-access, but i need to be hidden not password protected, if possible, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer here is "it depends"!
All databases have their advantages and disadvantages. The rule that applies here is that depending on the use you want to do, choose respectively.

The strengths of MySQL for example is low cost (free if you ever need community support), the ability to run on any platform but also significant flexibility in remote management.

The MS SQL is also very stable, provides storage processes, transactions and other powerful features. However less cost and simplicity of management with respect to MySQL. Of course Express Edition is a good and sufficient solution for many circumstances.

If you would like a more specific suggestion you must provide us with some more information and features for the application you want to develop.

Comment: thx sir, i think i can use that ms-access, it is only to store some inventory data as well as web url and passwords. thx

Answer (score 0):

1. Database should be password protected
2. Use Encrypting Strategy to save password

May be below article help you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx

Comment: thanks ,I know I can set password to ms-access database, but I asked what database is THE BEST to use in my case. Thanks