# How to password protect an SQLite3 db in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've already searched around and so far, what I've found isn't working for some reason :\

```
string connection = "Data Source=DB.db;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;";
SQLiteConnection sqlc = new SQLiteConnection(connection);
sqlc.Open();  
sqlc.SetPassword("password");

sqlc.Close();
```

Gives me the error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Hotel_Manager.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Note that I already have a program that interacts with the DB working. It's only now that I'm trying to password protect it.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with SQLite. I would hazard a guess that there's an error in your XAML. Does the code run if you comment out the SQLite bits?

Comment: It works perfectly if I take out the `sqlc.SetPassword("password");` bit :\

Comment: Can you update with the full text of that exception? Suspect the inner exception will give an answer here...

Comment: @DeanWard Just did! It basically points to the line the password bit is at.

Comment: @Lloyd I'm pretty sure it doesn't work that way? :)) But thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @Dilisqq that still isn't the full exception; need the full stack trace... I think you might need to call ChangePassword. See answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible

Comment: JUST FIGURED IT OUT!

@DeanWard It should be sqlc.ChangePasword() not sqlc.SetPassword(). How stupid of me ~_~

Comment: @DeanWard Funny, we typed it out together at the same time haha. But yeah, that's the right answer. Thanks for helping me out! :)