# PHP SQLite password protected database

Tags: php, database, sqlite, passwords, database-connection

I am looking for a way to have a password protected SQLite Database being created and accessed throughout PHP. So far I found two ways to set a password in .NET ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection/5877130#5877130)) but not in PHP...

If there is any way to do that, in the "default" PHP (no plugins, but PHP libraries allowed), please enlighten me!

Edit: I shall also mention that I do not have the rights to install plugins, on the hosting account I have.

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection. Very useful to you.

Comment: @[anant-kumar-singh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354071/php-sqlite-password-protected-database#comment46893386_29354071): I forgot to mention that I need this to work with the "default" php, which means no plugins, addons or other admin-side executables. Only "good ol' PHP"... and that link was also found in my post at the time I published it, so I surely checked it. I also re-checked, to make sure I did not missed anything, but no change...