# Set password for SQLite v3 database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

My application uses a database stored in a file available via network. So far, I've been using a **MS-Access** file (.accdb), but I'm trying to migrate to **SQLite Version 3 (.db3)**.

I added SQLite NuGet package to my project and created a SQLite database using [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl). I refactored my database objects to work with `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection` instead of `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection` and it worked well.

However, my previous `accdb` database was password protected, and I don't know how to apply a password over my current SQLite database.

Can anyone teach me ho to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible) will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1381264/1070452) which  [Wudge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6143965/wudge) kindly appointed in comment above, and it works, but I'd rather clarify what need to be done:

1. To set a password to an unprotected database:

   ```
   Dim conn = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(
       "Data Source=C:\yourFolder\yourDB.db3;Version=3;")
   conn.Open()
   conn.ChangePassword("password")
   conn.Close()
   ```
2. To open a password-protected database:

   ```
   Dim conn = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(
       "Data Source=C:\yourFolder\yourDB.db3;Version=3;")
   conn.SetPassword("password")
   conn.Open()
   conn.Close()
   ```

   or

   ```
   Dim conn = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(
       "Data Source=C:\yourFolder\yourDB.db3;Version=3;Password=password;")
   conn.Open()
   conn.Close()
   ```
3. To remove password from a password-protected database:

   ```
   Dim conn = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(
       "Data Source=C:\yourFolder\yourDB.db3;Version=3;Password=password;")
   conn.Open()
   conn.ChangePassword(String.Empty)
   conn.Close()
   ```

**PS.** The open source database manager [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl) is able to open files which were password-protected that way, as long as you choose `System.Data.SQLite` instead of `Sqlite 3` as your database type. (Requires v 3.1.1, the current version).

Comment: Hi VBobCat, I'm doing the same in my vb.net project, but It does't work and I don't understand what I'm getting wrong.

I'm using  System.Data.SQLite (downloaded offccial sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe). 
Managers used DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.10.1 and SQliteStudio too.

I've tryed setting password from code and from DB Browser

This is my code:
Dim mDbConnection as String = "Data Source= C:\TestDB.s3db;Version=3;
Dim cnn As New SQLiteConnection(mDbConnection)
cnn.SetPassword("test")
cnn.Open()
cnn.Close()

Comment: This exception:
File opened that is not a database file  file is encrypted or is not a database

Comment: No idea. But I had some trouble in the past, thinking I'd set up a password and in fact it was not set. In SQLiteStudio, right-click your database root icon and choose "Edit the Database" so you can see if a password was actually set. Beyond that, I'm clueless.

Comment: Even if I've set the password in DB Broswer, SQLiteStudio doesn't like it and If I actually would to set a password in SQLiteStudio I don't find how can I do it.
So:
I 've opend db without password setted by code (similar above code), I immediately changed Password to set it (cnn.ChangePassword("test")), and now everytime I want to open db the string "Data Source= C:\TestDB.s3db;Version=3;Password=test" works.
And after this I can manage the db with SQLiteStudio.
Thank you!