# What are the password restrictions for encrypting an SQLite3 database?

Tags: sqlite, passwords

What are the allowed characters for the passphrase? Are all unicode valid?

(SQLite documentation search gives back no results for "password")

For length I read [here](https://forum.xojo.com/47338-sqlite-database-encryption-key-limited-to-16-characters/0) that it is considering only the first 16 characters of the password.

Comment: Sqlite itself doesn't do encryption or passwords. Which extension are you using to get that functionality?

Comment: I saw sqlite connection with password [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible) with C#. Ultimately I'd like to do this through java. And also I saw this encryption part of sqlite [here](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/readme.wiki). (Well part: extension)