# Where is "SetPassword" or "ChangePassword" in SQLiteConnection class?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm just learning how to encrypt/decrypt SQLite database.
I found a way to encrypt, as in this post [SQLite with encryption/password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection/5877130#5877130)

This page's best answer said that we can use `SEE`,`wxSQLite`,`SQLCipher`,`SQLiteCrypt`, etc... to encrypt.

I can understand.

And, another answer said that we can use:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
conn.SetPassword("password");
conn.open();
```

This page also says the same:
[Password Protect a SQLite DB. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible)

However, `SQLiteConnection` doesn't have `SetPassword` nor `ChangePassword` methods. 
I'm very confused.

Where are `SetPasword` or `ChangePassword`?
Are these in `SEE`, `wxSQLite`,`SQLCipher`,`SQLiteCrypt`?

> [Development environment]
>   VisualStudio2010  .NET Framework 4
>   Client Profile  System.Data.SQLite.dll 
>   (https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

I downloaded zip from there, and I picked up "System.Data.SQLite.dll"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password Protect a SQLite DB. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible)

Comment: No, It is’nt. my question is Where "SetPasword" or "ChangePassword" is. SQLiteConnection doesn’t have these method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQLite no longer has "SetPassword" or "ChangePassword".

To initially set the password you use the following:

```
var connectionString = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(baseConnectionString)
{
    Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate,
    Password = password
}.ToString();
```

To change the password you would do the following:

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT quote($newPassword);";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$newPassword", newPassword);
var quotedNewPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

command.CommandText = "PRAGMA rekey = " + quotedNewPassword;
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Oh, you mean “System.Data.SQLite had these method before. but now nothing”, right?

Comment: Correct. But they only worked in .Net Framework projects. They have never been available in .Net Standard or .Net Core.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can understand.

Comment: By the way, I tried your suggested code. But, I couldn't set password, And couldn't open encrypted database.  
Your code is for SQLCipher library?
I found same code in Microsoft documentation. "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Although it is mentioned in Microsoft docs, however, Sqlite db file would still open without password.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to encrypt/decrypt SQLite database. there are some information for you

Please check the [Specify the key section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli&fbclid=IwAR1HRSlIcmXORyHaoU--ugMmaQAJ3vFheQXx672jkjfnTzIdmsWstkfURtE#specify-the-key) in the official documentation if you have other problem.

> The method for encrypting and decrypting existing databases varies depending on which solution you're using. For example, you need to use the sqlcipher_export() function on SQLCipher. Check your solution's documentation for details.

You can use the SQLCipher API to finish your work:

1. If you want to build a encrypting database,
   just set your connection string, like this:`Data Source = encryptedName.db; Password=YourPassword`
2. if you want to change password in a encrypting database

   ```
   // you can use this in startup.cs
   using var changePasswordDb = new DBContext(
       new SqliteConnection(
               new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder()
                   {
                        DataSource = "encryptedName.db",
                        Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate,
                        Password = oldPassword
                   }.ToString()
           ));
   changePasswordDb.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"PRAGMA rekey = {newPassword}");

   // or use SqliteConnection
   var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source =encryptedName.db.db;Password=yourPassword");
   connection.Open();
   var command = connection.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = "PRAGMA rekey = " + newPassword;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```
3. if you want to encrypt a plaintext SQLite database ,  SQLCipher is not support directly. so you can use sqlcipher_export() to get the goal.
   look this [How to encrypt a plaintext SQLite database to use SQLCipher (and avoid “file is encrypted or is not a database” errors)](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/how-to-encrypt-a-plaintext-sqlite-database-to-use-sqlcipher-and-avoid-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database-errors/868)

```
// Example
command.CommandText = "ATTACH DATABASE 'encryptedName.db' AS encrypted KEY 'YourNewPassword';SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');DETACH DATABASE encryptedName;";
```

4. if you have some Performance Issue in Asp.net Core and Entity Framework Core ,
   you need to check to these

- [Performance with SQLite and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23099)
- [Entity Framework Core connection management](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/46714416/entity-framework-core-connection-management)
- [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite: Pool Connections #13837](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13837)

5. if you have other Performance Issue , you can check this [SQLCipher Performance Optimization](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-performance-optimization/14)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that starting with System.Data.SQLite **version 1.0.113.0**, support for encryption via `SetPassword()` and `ChangePassword()` was removed.
See my answer here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72073407/8586332