# c# system.data.sqlite V 10.113.1 SQLiteConnection.ChangePassword missing

Tags: c#, sqlite

In version V 1.0.113.1 of package system.data.sqlite the function ChangePassword is no longer supported.

Users must have the possibility to change the password of an SQLite database. I know this function of SQLite for many years.

In the forum SQLite you can find the poor statement that the function is "not supported" and therefore dropped. If this remains so, you will be forced to change to another database system in the future, or is there another possibility to change the password of a database?

Comment: I would suspect that the package developers have reasoned that changing the password is an administrative task and doesn't really belong in this package - I would look to see if there's another package covering admin interactions

Comment: The function has been in existence for about 15 years. It is not possible to understand why it has been dropped. I will rollback to version 1.0.112 and use a different database system in the future, because SQLite is not backward compatible. A disaster for existing applications.

Comment: Maybe this link is a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294577/where-is-setpassword-or-changepassword-in-sqliteconnection-class?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: see other options here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005918/426315