# Sqlite connection string with encrypted password

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have an encrypted database using **"SQLite Cipher"**. When I try to connect to the database using Connection string the following error message appears:

> 'SQL logic error Cannot use "Password" connection string property: library was not built with encryption support.'

[image: Code With Error]

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Public Class frm_projects
    Dim dtset As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Setting.db;Password=m;")

    Private Sub frm_projects_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            If dtset.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                dtset.Open()

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Warning")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

[Image From DB Browser sqlite Cipher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P91lS.png)

Comment: Are we allowed to see your code where you're creating the connection?

Comment: Dim dtset As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Setting.db;Password=m;")
        Try
            If dtset.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                dtset.Open()
                MsgBox("Connection Success!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Informations")
                'list_projects.Items.Add("ANa")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Failed to connect to SQLite Database", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Warning")
        End Try

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6TUVKRI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41426738/10216583

Comment: Please stop posting information vital to the question in comments. Apart from the fact that code is barely readable in comments even when formatted - you haven't even formatted it - no one should have to read the comments to understand the question. If you have omitted vital information from the question then edit the question and provide it.

Comment: You say *"the following message appears"* but of course it does, because your code displays it. How about you look at the actual exception that was thrown and see what message it provides? That's what's supposed to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I am new to this community
I modified the post
The problem is that whenever I want to open a connection with the encrypted database I cannot access it

Comment: @JQSOFT don't work

Comment: Check your connection string. What is `Data Source=Setting.db` ? This should be the path of the database. Maybe you mean: `Dim dtset As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={My.Settings.db};Password=m;")` where `db` is a string property in your Application settings.

Comment: @JQSOFT Setting.db is sqlite database file in  Application path directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Source of the issue

I assume that the actual reason for this error is the the lack of support in "legacy CryptoAPI" since `System.Data.SQLite` version **~1.0.113.1**.

It was done in the following commit:
https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/1dd56c9fd59a10fd

## What can we do?

1. **Manually** Use the last NuGet version with CryptoAPI support - **1.0.112.2**.

   Notice - It **must** be done manually - either by editing `PackageReference` in `csproj` or by editing `config.packages`.
   the reason is that older versions are unlisted (!) from [the NuGet feed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/):
   [image: NuGet feed only shows ONE version]
2. Buy perpetual source code license for `SQLite Encryption Extension` (`SEE`) which costs one time fee of 2000$ (as of Feb 2021) - [purchase link](https://sqlite.org/purchase/see)
3. Use `SQLCipher` - SQLCipher is an SQLite extension that provides 256 bit AES encryption of database files - [GitHub source](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) (haven't tested it myself!)

## Data Sources

- https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=9c330a3e03
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64392325/426315

Answer (score 1):

Change System.data.sqlite by this package [Link](http://system.data.sqlite.org/blobs/1.0.94.0/sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-Win32-2010-1.0.94.0.zip)

To set a password to an unprotected database:

```
Dim conn = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(
    "Data Source=C:\yourFolder\yourDB.db3;Version=3;")
conn.Open()
conn.ChangePassword("password")
conn.Close()
```

To open a password-protected database:

```
Dim conn = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(
    "Data Source=C:\yourFolder\yourDB.db3;Version=3;")
conn.SetPassword("password")
conn.Open()
conn.Close()
```

or

```
Dim conn = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(
    "Data Source=C:\yourFolder\yourDB.db3;Version=3;Password=password;")
conn.Open()
conn.Close()
```

To remove password from a password-protected database:

```
Dim conn = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(
    "Data Source=C:\yourFolder\yourDB.db3;Version=3;Password=password;")
conn.Open()
conn.ChangePassword(String.Empty)
conn.Close()
```

Note: The open source database manager SQLiteStudio is able to open files which were password-protected that way, as long as you choose System.Data.SQLite instead of Sqlite 3 as your database type. (Requires v 3.1.1, the current version).