# System.Data.SQLite.Core Cannot use "Password" connection string property

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, system.data.sqlite

I am writing a .NET Core 3.1 application that depends on another library (*Serilog.Sinks.SQLite*) which is attempting to store log data to an SQLite database. Unfortunately, *Serilog.Sinks.SQLite* does not support passing in a password to *System.Data.SQLite* via the `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder.Password` property (which you provide to the `SQLiteConnection` constructor) and I would really like that functionality.

The code that *Serilog.Sinks.SQLite* uses to connect to the database is as follows:

```
private SQLiteConnection GetSqLiteConnection()
{
    var sqlConString = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = _databasePath,
        JournalMode = SQLiteJournalModeEnum.Memory,
        SyncMode = SynchronizationModes.Normal,
        CacheSize = 500,
        PageSize = (int)MaxSupportedPageSize,
        MaxPageCount = (int)(_maxDatabaseSize * BytesPerMb / MaxSupportedPageSize)
    }.ConnectionString;

    var sqLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(sqlConString);
    sqLiteConnection.Open();

    return sqLiteConnection;
}
```

There are a number of similar posts on StackOverflow about encryption with SQLite stating very convincingly that encryption / password protection of the database is indeed supported by *System.Data.SQLite*. However, that is not matching my experience.

I grabbed a copy of the [Serilog.Sinks.SQLite source](https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-sqlite) in an attempt to prototype a modification to it to support specifying the password. This seems like it should be easy enough to accomplish with the following addition to the above code (specifying the Password property in the connection string):

```
        MaxPageCount = (int)(_maxDatabaseSize * BytesPerMb / MaxSupportedPageSize),
        Password = "mypasswordhere"
    }.ConnectionString;
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and results in an exception being thrown on startup with the following message:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException An
> unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException'
> occurred in LoggingWebApi.dll: 'SQL logic error Cannot use "Password"
> connection string property: library was not built with encryption
> support, please see "https://www.sqlite.org/see" for more information'

What is confusing me the most here are the number of other posts I've found claiming that *System.Data.SQLite* supports this password *and* the fact that a .NET Framework 4.6 application from another team in my company is using System.Data.SQLite.dll (though an older version 1.0.111.0) and this Password behavior works fine for them.

My code is targeting `netcoreap3.1` and my dependency of `Serilog.Sinks.SQLite` is targeting `netstandard2.0` so that is one obvious difference I see. In my modified version of the `Serilog.Sinks.SQLite` code, I am referencing `System.Data.SQLite.Core` as follows (added via `otnet add package System.Data.SQLite.Core --version 1.0.113.1`):

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.113.1" />
```

Is there something with .NET Core 3.1 or .NET Standard 2.0 that causes System.Data.SQLite.Core to not support the Password connection string property like everyone else seems to think it supports?

I thought maybe my issue was running on Linux so I tried running on my Windows but it produced the same error.

I did find another post referencing a potentially helpful approach but this sample is not using `System.Data.SQLite.Core` and instead is using `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher` and I would prefer to avoid rewriting all of the *Serilog.Sinks.SQLite* code to use a different SQLite client: https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore

Comment: I found this github thread:[How to make SQLite database password protected](https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-sqlite/issues/26), we are not sure whether the Serilog.Sinks.SQLite package supports password encrypted databases or not, you could also contact to the Serilog.Sinks.SQLite or post a comment to verify it. If it not supports, you have to [use SQLite encrypted databases using Entity Framework Core (EFCore)](https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore)

Comment: I did some more testing and found that if I make a Windows .NET Framework (4.7.2) application and reference the System.Data.SQLite.Core from NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/), it also does not support encryption. So it would seem the version available to the public on NuGet does not support encryption.

Comment: If that is the case, you could try to [use SQLite encrypted databases using Entity Framework Core (EFCore)](https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that System.Data.SQLite has dropped support for encryption as of version 1.0.113.1 which explains why I haven't been able to get it working:
https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=9c330a3e03

This is also mentioned on their News page though it was not clear to me that the Password support was part of the "legacy CryptoAPI Codec":
https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

The other team I referred to is using an older version 1.0.111.0 so if you require this support, I guess just don't upgrade...