# Can't open sqlite database since System.Data.SQLite from Nuget updated to version 1.0.113.6 in WinForms software

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, encryption

I am working on a WinForm software and i use SQLite database in it.

Today i updated **System.Data.SQLite** from (**Nuget**) to version **1.0.113.6** and *since then i get error at ChangePassword method in SQLiteConnection*. I search for other method for password, i can't find any.

Also i can't open my database that has password that i set from older version of **System.Data.SQlite** and it always gives me

> "SQL logic error Cannot use "Password" connection string property:
> library was not built with encryption support, please see
> "https://www.sqlite.org/see" for more information"

error when i try to connect to my database.

Is there anyway to enable opening encrypted databases or set password to new databases by this new SQLite update?

Update:
I read that CryptoAPI in SQLlite got discontinued and my software assign a password for all databases that create it without password.

Is there a way to open these databases or at least remove the encryption?

Comment: please take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005918/426315) answer