# Does the latest version of System.Data.Sqlite not support password encryption?

Tags: .net-core, system.data.sqlite

I've got a .Net Core appl and am using the System.Data.SQLite.dll package to connect to a SQLite DB.

I'm trying to encrypt the database with a password.

In version **1.0.93.0** of **System.Data.SQLite.dll** library I can set or change the password encryption of the database:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source=DBName;Version=3;");
conn.SetPassword($"{password}");
conn.ChangePassword($"{password}");
conn.Open();
```

In the latest version **1.0.113.7** the api's no longer to appear to be supported.
Visual Studio throws a compiler error on the SetPassword() and ChangePassword() calls.

How do I password encrypt my databases?
Is there another way to achieve this using this library (or something similar)?

Comment: This has been asked before, though I don't know if you'll find the answers very satisfying. [Where is "SetPassword" or "ChangePassword" in SQLiteConnection class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294577/where-is-setpassword-or-changepassword-in-sqliteconnection-class)

Comment: SQLite itself doesn't support encryption. It's always provided by customized libraries like SQLCipher. This is explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli), which show how to use encryption through SQLCipher

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it seems that starting with System.Data.SQLite **version 1.0.113.0, support for encryption in this way was entirely removed** in [this checkin](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/56170d1316782f1b), by modifying the file `/Targets/SQLite.NET.Settings.targets`, and setting the value of `InteropCodec` to false.

Specifically the comment says "Merge all changes needed for the SQLite core library 3.32.0 release."

This reveals to us that the actual culprit is SQLite itself, where in **release 3.32.0, they removed support for this type of encryption API as well**, in [this commit](https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/5a877221ce90e752), where the comment says "**simplify the code by removing the unsupported and undocumented SQLITE_HAS_CODEC compile-time option**"

**Neither the change in System.Data.SQLite nor in SQLite are documented in the release notes for these projects.**

In prior versions of System.Data.SQLite, such as 1.0.112.1 and earlier, encryption via the SetPassword() method was supported, and this used the “SQLite Encryption Extension” (SEE)

Comment: Added note for those of us who end up here eons later... I was getting errors with 112 only working in framework projects, ended up finding 1.0.106.0 works for framework, core and netstandard.

Comment: Actually looks like one can get to 1.0.108.0.  Lots of unlisted packages and trying to poke though to get things working.  108 works, 109 fails to connect.