# c# inmemory SQLite database to Stream

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to protect the data of my SQLite database before shipping my Unity game either by setting an encryption password or using a Binary writer, and I find the online documentation very light/confusing.

I am using System.Data.SQlite.dll now. The first versions of my game were only on windows and I could use the password properties but never on mac, and now this feature seems to have been removed anyway ([Where is "SetPassword" or "ChangePassword" in SQLiteConnection class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294577/where-is-setpassword-or-changepassword-in-sqliteconnection-class))

I'm using inmemory database that and I call BackupDatabase to save my db to the disk.

I explored the option to backup my inmemory database to a Stream and use a Binary writer to save my file but haven't succeeded.

My indie game does not have the resources to buy products like SQLCypher (499$ per platform), I find it misleading that the only example on microsoft's documentation is about a non free third party (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli )

Am I missing something or there isn't any free alternative allowing to have basic encryption on my sqlite database?

Comment: Why you haven't succeded with the binary stream?

Comment: Nothing you do is going to protect against a detemined user with access to a debugger.

Comment: the goal is not to go against a determined user but to not give away our data to anyone with a keyboard.

Comment: I didn't succeed with the Binary Stream because I was not good enough with Unmanaged programming to change the source of the System.Data.SQLite.dll project myself.